# Genexus 15 upgrade 11 Webnotifications throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.genexus.internet.websocket.GXWebSocket

Tags: genexus

I have a project made on genexus 15 from start and working fine until upgrade 11.

As soon as I upgraded to U11 all my webnotifications stoped working and throws:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.genexus.internet.websocket.GXWebSocket
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1136)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at com.genexus.internet.GXWebNotification.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.genexuscore.genexus.web.notifications.SdtWebNotification.notify(SdtWebNotification.java:56)
```

I made a full rebuild and I even deleted .ari from state to force a full generation, used the new GxClassR installed on my pc and the class is still missing.

I have also made clean deploys, and it still gives the same error.

Does anyone knows the "new" Jar i'm missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the solution: 
Somehow since U11 the deploy feature and the generation and compile doesn't add the GXWebSocket.jar (under the genexus instalation) file by default, I had to put it on the .war file under lib and it works, the same for all the Applications.